# How to check if bit 55 MSR register is set

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel

Is this the correct C code to check whether bit 55 of an MSR register is set or not ?

```
uint32_t l, h;

    rdmsr(IA32_VMX_BASIC, l, h);

    if((h>>23)&& 1)
    {
        pr_info("BIT SET\n");

    }
    else
    {
        pr_info("NOT SET\n"); 
    }
```

Comment: No, you have to use single `&` to perform bitwise operation.

Comment: 55 is too long for an `uint32_t`, use `uint64_t` or  `unsigned long long` and then check if `(h & (1ULL << 55))`

Comment: And please also check `rdmsr` arguments since you are passing `l` and `h` arguments by value but they are probably return values. Check the documentation of `rdmsr`.

Comment: @KeineLust those are probably low and high 32-bit parts of 64-bit number.

Comment: @vasek, then the title is wrong

Comment: So @ams, check `h & (1UL << (55-32))`

Comment: @KeineLust I believe OP wants to check bit 55 of MSR register, but yes, title is confusing.